# Creating a NavigationStrategy in Aurelia

Tags: wordpress, aurelia

I'm trying to use Aurelia as my platform for a custom Wordpress theme.

What I want to do is define my navigation menu in Wordpress, use the Wordpress plugin for menus to expose the menus through the Wordpress API as a JSON string and then building the navigation menu in Aurelia.

Everything I have found so far involves creating a simple one line menu.

Has anyone done this or can point me in the right direction?

Comment: It's not really clear what you are asking. If you need to create hierarchical (multi-level) menu, take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41577897/aurelia-easy-way-to-create-nested-multi-level-navigation-menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using server-side data to build your navigation menu, you might as well let the server do the hard work and let it generate a ready-to-use configuration for your router.

Let your plugin generate JSON like this:

```
{
  "routes": [
    {
      "route": "\"...\"",
      "moduleId": "\"...\"",
      "settings": {
        "childRoutes": [
          {
            "route": "\"...\"",
            "moduleId": "\"...\"",
          }
        ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Then in your root view model's configureRouter you could do something like this:

```
async configureRouter(config, router) {
  const resp = await http.fetch("api/menu-plugin-uri");
  const json = await resp.json();
  config.map(json.routes);
}
```

The child routes are stored in the `settings` object of the config, meaning we can use it for building a navigation menu and we can access it in child routes like so:

```
configureRouter(config, router) {
  const parentConfig = router.parent.currentInstruction.config;
  config.map(parentConfig.childRoutes);
}
```

That doesn't give you nice `NavModel`s with `isActive` and everything, but this is about as good as it gets when it comes to nested navigation menu's currently.

I'm actually working on a [plugin](https://github.com/fkleuver/aurelia-router-metadata) myself to try and address some of these limitations, though NOT ready for production yet.